# How to improve wild card query performance in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, performance, database

If I have a collection of 20 million records with a name field. And I want to run a query like db.collection.find({"name": /bob/}) to find all names that contain the word "bob". I know that an index will not help with this query. I am just wondering if there are other ways to improve the query speed? Thanks!

Comment: An index on `name` will still help as it will be scanned instead of the full docs themselves.

Answer (score 2):

You could add a `$text` index on the `name` column:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { name: "text" } )
```

and do a search for bob in the `name` column using this query:

```
db.collection.find( { $text: { $search: "bob" } } )
```

Comment: This wouldn't find Bobby though, as bob isn't an English stem of Bobby.

Comment: Yes you are correct @JohnnyHK, I have removed the last section about `Bobby` from my answer

Comment: Has this changed at all since then? I cannot seem to find a way to do this efficiently still (except by using a regex search, which is too slow).